# Syntax Error while using recode command in SPSS

Tags: spss

```
DO IF  (WB4 = 1). 
    RECODE WB5 (0=0) (1=1) (2=2) (3=3) (4=4) (5=5) INTO WB5_1.
    IF  (WB4 = 2). 
    RECODE WB5 (0=5) (1=6) (2=7) (3=8) INTO WB5_1. 
    IF  (WB4 = 3). 
    RECODE WB5 (0=8) (1=9) (2=10) INTO WB5_1. 
    IF  (WB4 = 4). 
    RECODE WB5 (0=10) (1=11) (2=12) (3=13) (4=14) (5=15) (6=16) (7=17) INTO WB5_1. 
END IF. 
EXECUTE.
```

I am trying to develop a new variable using multiple options by connecting the options of two variables to create a new variable. Please guide me I have an error.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an error, you should post the error message with your question.

In this case, though, the problem is likely the use of the IF statement instead pf DO IF  IF takes only a simple statement like compute.  Instead use
DO IF condition.
RECODE ...
END IF.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by JKP, not posting the error makes it a bit difficult to fully debug your syntax.

One think I can tell you from the get go is that you are clearly miss-using the `IF` command: it needs to have 2 parameters:

`IF [condition] [transformation].`

You just have the condition, followed by the `RECODE` command; `IF` does not work that way.
It *can* work inside a `DO IF` `END IF` structure, but you need to provide both parameters.

Alternatively, you can use an `IF` `ELSE IF` `END IF` structure (you would just need to add the "else"s in your current syntax:

```
DO IF  (WB4 = 1). 
    RECODE WB5 (0=0) (1=1) (2=2) (3=3) (4=4) (5=5) INTO WB5_1.
    ELSE IF  (WB4 = 2). 
    RECODE WB5 (0=5) (1=6) (2=7) (3=8) INTO WB5_1. 
    ELSE IF  (WB4 = 3). 
    RECODE WB5 (0=8) (1=9) (2=10) INTO WB5_1. 
    ELSE IF  (WB4 = 4). 
    RECODE WB5 (0=10) (1=11) (2=12) (3=13) (4=14) (5=15) (6=16) (7=17) INTO WB5_1. 
END IF. 
EXECUTE.
```